# Gradle не импортирует мои библиотеки

Tags: android, gradle

Ребята, я добавил в градле библиотеку Picasso, но Gradle её не видит. Точнее когда я обновляю Gradle всё хорошо,он обновляется, но когда я пишу код связанный с Picasso, он подчёркивается красной чертой. Одним словом не видит библиотеку Picasso. Что не так?
Так же было и с Firebase: я прописывал все библиотеки вручную import...,ибо не видит эти библиотеки. Вот когда пропишешь,тогда да,всё работает.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На вид выглядит все правильно, вполне возможно что он подчеркивает и предлагает добавить импорт класса. Поставьте курсор на подчернутое имя, нажмите Alt+Enter и посмотрите какие там подскази есть. Так же напишите или приложите скрин как все это дело выглядит

Comment: @temq Вот в том-то и проблема,что раньше у меня выскакивал таким образом импорт библиотеки,а сейчас пропала эта фигня.
Скрин добавил в вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте подключить jar-файл.

Comment: может где-то в настройках самой android studio нужно что-то установить,не знаю даже...

Comment: @КириллМалышев это может и решит проблему, но мне придётся тогда всё время скачивать и добавлять. С Firebase такая же ерунда была.Проблема решилась ручным вводом библиотеки в коде: import com.google.firebase...

Comment: В этом сообществе могут помочь?

Comment: Проблема индивидуальная поэтому дать однозначный ответ проблематично. Попробуйте выполнить File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart

Comment: @temq помогло))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать несколько вариантов:

- Очистить кеш (`File` → `Invalidate cache / restart`)
- Очистить проект (`Build` → `Clean Project`)
- Пересобрать проект (`Build` → `Rebuild Project`)

Comment: Помогла очистка кеша!